# Tomcat redirecting to old file

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm having a problem with tomcat 6 and redirection. My servlet creates a class that generates a file on the tomcat server. At the end of the servlet's post method I call the redirect method so that the user can download this file. The user is redirected and prompted to download the file. The problem is the file is stale. It's the file that was there before I started the tomcat server. I even tried sleeping the thread before the redirection. Any ideas why they are being redirected to this stale file that no longer exists?

I'm using eclipse to start a tomcat server.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String outputName = "XXX\\workspace\\BlahOnline\\WebContent\\Blah.xlsm";
    String redirect = "Blah.xlsm";
    response.sendRedirect(redirect);
}
```

Edit: Nevermind, I found a better way to download the file using code in the servlet. This thread helped a lot: [Download mp3 file from Tomcat server with Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726672/download-mp3-file-from-tomcat-server-with-java-servlet)

Comment: Show us the code. Is the file being saved to the same location the download is getting it from?

Comment: Yes it has the same path, and also appears in the same directory. (It is overwriting the file that is there)

Comment: Show us how the file download is done.

Comment: If the redirection is going back to the browser and only then to the target URL of the file, then maybe the browser uses a file that was cached by the browser.

Comment: I think that might the problem, is there a way to clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to download a file from tomcat. I used Streams instead of redirecting to the user to the file. This thread helped a lot: [Download mp3 file from Tomcat server with Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726672/download-mp3-file-from-tomcat-server-with-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something like a TTL (timeToLife) that makes the server output the same as some minutes before. If the TTL is one hour it would output the same for an hour. Only after this hour it would update the answer-file.

Check out something like TTL configurations of your tomcat server.